# function to convert string to integer -- call to undefined function

Tags: php

I am creating a function that converts a users initials (STRING) to their userid (INT)

problem is when I call the function I get a call to undefined func error because the below declared function is no where to be found in the Source!

```
// connect to database -- this works, I checked it
function convertRadInitToRadID($radInits){
    $sqlGetRadID="SELECT id FROM sched_roster WHERE radInitials == '".$radInits."'";
    $resultGetRadID=mysql_query($sqlGetRadID);
    $radID=mysql_result($resultGetRadID,0);
    return $radID;
}
```

...I then create and array ($radNotOnVacay_and_NonMRNotonVacayWeekBeforeAndAfter) of user initials, it works with no errors I tested it independently

```
$randKey=rand(0,(count($radNotOnVacay_and_NonMRNotonVacayWeekBeforeAndAfter)-1));
$randRad=$radNotOnVacay_and_NonMRNotonVacayWeekBeforeAndAfter[$randKey];
$randAssignedRadID=convertRadInitToRadID($randRad);  // call to undefined function error here
```

when I view source the function definition code (where I define the function) is nowhere to be seen in the source.  Very strange.  I tried placing it around different areas of the script, same error.  The function definition is declared appropriately and is wrapped in .

Very strange.  The function just doesn't appear.  Quotations, syntax, semi-colons, etc are all spot on.

No syntax errors.  Advice?

Comment: first change 'radInitials == ' to 'radInitials ='

Comment: `$radNotOnVacay_and_NonMRNotonVacayWeekBeforeAndAfter` is not an acceptable variable name. How do you hope to not exceed the 80-character limit?

Answer (score 1):

I Strongly agree with Answer #1.

In addition a usual problems occur in php if you are defining function after calling it. i.e. your calling code is before function defination then it will not run and will give an error of undefined function.

You can create a class then define this function in that class and on the time of calling you can call that function with help of $this->function(args)

I think this will resolve your problem in mean while i am trying to run your code on my machine, lets see what happen

Answer (score 0):

May be your function is a method of some class. So, if it is, you should use it in another way:

```
MyClass::convertRadInitToRadID($radInits) // if static method
```

or like this

```
$class = new MyClass();
$class ->convertRadInitToRadID($radInits)
```

Answer (score -1):

Trying to make sense of your question... Are you trying to call the function using JavaScript? If so, remember that JavaScript is run on the browser, and PHP is run on the server (and this is why when you "view source" you don't see the function anywhere). To send data back from JavaScript to PHP you should use AJAX.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer: I was using Jquery UI tabs.... there must be a conflict with tabs.  When I run the code without tabs there is no issue.

Thanks for the '==' fix.. appreciate it. my bad

thanks for reminding me about the 80 char varname code limit